# php password hash and verify !false

Tags: php

What am I missing with the `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions in **PHP5.5** because it doesnt work for me.

If I do the hash and verify as one line, it works:

```
php -r "var_dump(password_verify('123', password_hash('123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)));"
bool(true)
```

but if I separate them on to two lines, it doesnt work:

```
php -r "var_dump(password_hash('123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));"
string(60) "$2y$10$UTURqRiTDZBx.M9eCTZEmOwTdA5KwKDn2UcdjYFTs2M8egXe/xP3O"

php -r "var_dump(password_verify('123', '$2y$10$UTURqRiTDZBx.M9eCTZEmOwTdA5KwKDn2UcdjYFTs2M8egXe/xP3O'));"
bool(false)
```

Comment: You might need to escape the `/`.

Comment: Might be an encoding issue in your terminal

Comment: @rocket - happens with all passwords. plus the single quotation means i dont have to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is your shell that is interpreting some of the characters before running the command. If you are using Bash as your shell then the $ character means the start of a variable. You will have to escape these characters so that Bash does not interfere

```
php -r "var_dump(password_verify('123', '\$2y\$10\$UTURqRiTDZBx.M9eCTZEmOwTdA5KwKDn2UcdjYFTs2M8egXe/xP3O'));"
```

This will return

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: that does indeed work but how come this also has to be done in a webpage?

Comment: It shouldn't have to be done in a web page. As long as you are using single quote for a string or else you would need to escape the $. And good catch.

Comment: @Christian I dont understand your question. If you have an additional problem that does not involve the shell then please create a new question for that separate issue and I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: @codeaken - ok, there isnt anywhere to share php code for version 5.5! ill just create another question and link it from here

Comment: @codeaken - no need for a new question. When i was copying the pw into the database, i had accidentally copied a space at the beginning. But thanks for answering the question above :)